# Converter with collection

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, collections, converters

in WPF, in my XAML i have a dataGrid binded on a IEnumerable. The collection items have a proprety called Sealed. To know if the order is sealed or not. So i've made a converter to switch it from one list to another. Altought, when i change the collection from the outside the converter is not being called. But if i close and reopen the window it works fine.

```
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = (ObservableCollection<OrderEntry>)value;
        var viewSource = new CollectionViewSource()
        {
            Source = collection,
        };
        viewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterInSealedOrderEntries);
        return viewSource.View;
    }

    private static void FilterInSealedOrderEntries(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        var orderEntry = e.Item as OrderEntry;
        e.Accepted = orderEntry != null && orderEntry.Sealed;
    }
```

"`{Binding Path=OrderEntries.Collection, Converter={StaticResource ViewNotSealedOrderEntryCollectionValueConverter}}`"

In my Xaml.

Whenever i change the property, the `collectionContentChanged` is being called but not the converter, any idea what am i doing wrong?

Thanks, i will comment if it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your specifying the `ValueConverter` in the `Binding` for the `DataGrid` `ItemsSource` it will only be called on initially populating the items.

Answer (score 0):

IValueConverter interface also contains ConvertBack method. I don't see this method in your code

Comment: public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
          object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

Comment: Try to analyze Output Window in your Visual Studio. It writes all binding warnings and exceptions

Comment: Yeah, i see that, tho, there is nothing related the dataGrid itemsSource. If i set a break point to the collectionContentChanged, it passes but not by the converter. Not quite sure what's happening.

Comment: Put a breakpoint to Convert method. I think something wrong with viewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterInSealedOrderEntries);
        return viewSource.View;

Comment: Read this post http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=31, and use CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView() then filtering via predicate